# How to change the width and height with an iframe and a mobile query?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I can't seem to be able to change the width or height on my website, what am I doing wrong here? Here's my website if it's easier to check ut out: http://sstromberg.saldev.nl/gmaps.html

Ignore the menu, still working on that.

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .locatie {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .locatie iframe {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="locatie">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2434.6620047353485!2d6.265314715523063!3d52.3946772797907!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c7e676b805f373%3A0x82055a9731e6d8ba!2sLandstede!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1513254153672" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error - add another { to the end of the `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)` line

Comment: @Xoog Whoops, forgot to add that on here. Here's my website if it's easier to check it out: http://sstromberg.saldev.nl/gmaps.html

Ignore the menu, still working on that.

Comment: So what are you wanting to change the width and height of? Presumably the map yeah?

Comment: Yes, it looks too small on mobile if I don't change it.

Comment: Looks fine to me - open developer console (f12) and toggle the device toolbar.

Comment: I copied the code from my website to my current file, now it looks good on most mobile phones, but if I change the height to % it suddenly makes itself very small, but its fine with px, how can I fix that?






Code:
.locatie {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
.locatie iframe {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Device-width refers to the display's resolution (eg. the 1024 from 1024x768), while width refers to the width of the browser itself (which will be different from the resolution if the browser isn't maximized). If your resolution is large enough to get you in one break point, but the width of the browser is small enough to get you in another one, you'll end up with an odd combination of both.

Unless you have a legitimate reason to restrict the style sheets based on the resolution and not the size of the viewport, then just use min-width/max-width and avoid min-device-width/max-device-width.

```
@media only  screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
.locatie {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        text-align: center;
        }

.locatie iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
}
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XZYSgaXQGGj9AehhZ0tH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@media(min-width:0px) and (max-width:768) {

.locatie iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: according to your;
}

}
```

In mobile you can use  `100%` it's batter to responsive not `PX`